# How to storing different subclass objects in an array in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

New to Swift here..

I have several subclassed objects from `UITableViewCell`, and I would like to store them in a single array, e.g. `[CustomCellA(), CustomCellB(), ...etc]`.

I have the following code:

```
    func register<T: UITableViewCell>(_ cells: [T.Type]) {
        cells.forEach { register($0) }
    }
```

and it seems like it can only take in 1 of the same exact type, even though it appears that I have scoped it to UITableViewCell.

Is there a way to make it accept all objects derived from UITableViewCells in the array? I remembered I could do this in Objective-C easily though..

Edit: added some sample code:

```
extension UITableView {
    func register<T: UITableViewCell>(_ cell: T.Type,
                                      forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: String = T.identifier) {
        register(cell.nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
    }
    // This is the one.
    func register<T: UITableViewCell>(_ cells: [T.Type]) {
        cells.forEach { register($0) }
    }
}
```

The above code is intended to simplify the `register` of the `UITableViewCell`s, so that I can simply call `tableView.register(CustomCellA.self)`, and I wanted to build on that, so that I can call `tableView.register([CustomCellA.self, CustomCellB.self])`. The one with array is giving me the problem.

I tried

```
    func register(_ cells: [UITableViewCell]) {
        cells.forEach { register($0) }
    }
```

but it won't work: cannot convert value of type 'UITableViewCell' to expected argument type '[UITableViewCell]'. I think it is not able to detect the first function and also it won't be able to send in its own identifier

Comment: Add a minimum reproducible example

Comment: Wouldn't `func register(_ cells: [UITableViewCell.Type])` work?

Comment: You don't need generics.  You can simply declare an array of `UITableViewCell`

Comment: I have added some sample code

Comment: Try to haves named parameter to differentiate the 2 register func. eg : register(cells : [UITableViewCell])

Comment: Even with the function name change it has the same errors: `cannot convert value of type 'CustomCellA.Type' to expected element type 'Array< CustomCellB.Type>.ArrayLiteralElement' (aka 'CustomCellB.Type')`